# Ember modal routing to wrong url on close

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I have an ember application which has a `users` model with CRUD capabilities. The `Create` and `Edit` templates are both rendered in twitter bootstrap modals. My problem is, when I click on `Cancel` or `Save Changes` in the modal, I want the app to return to the `users` template. Instead when I click either of these buttons, the modal disappears but the url remains at /users/create or /users/edit respectively. I've tried to change the routing as below, but it has had no effect. My modals are the result of a lot of googling and putting together code from different examples, so I'm not sure if the `close` action in `userEditView` actually does anything. Can anyone help?

```
App.UserEditView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: "user/edit",
    title: "",
    content: "",
    classNames: ["modal", "fade"],
    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.$().modal("show");
        this.$().one("hidden", this._viewDidHide);
    },
    // modal dismissed by example clicked in X, make sure the modal view is destroyed
    _viewDidHide: function() {
        if (!this.isDestroyed) {
            this.destroy();
        }
    },
    // here we click in close button so _viewDidHide is called
    close: function() {        
        this.$(".close").click();

//This is where I've tried to change the routing

this.transitionToRoute('users');

    }
});
```

My template:

```
<script type = "text/x-handlebars" id = "user/edit">

<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit User</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
<div class = "input-group">
  <h5>First Name</h5>
  {{input value=firstName}}

  <h5>Last Name</h5>
  {{input value=lastName}}

  <h5>Email</h5>
  {{input value=email}}


      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">

        <a {{action close target="view"}} href="#" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
        <a {{action "save"}} class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>

      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->

</script>
```

My controller:

```
   App.UsersCreateController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({


      actions: {
        save: function(){
          console.log("this.get('model')", this.get('model'));

          // create a record and save it to the store
          var newUser = this.store.createRecord('user', this.get('model'));
          console.log("newUser", newUser);
          newUser.save();

          // redirects to the user itself
          this.transitionToRoute('user', newUser);
        }
      }
    });
```

And my route:

```
App.UsersCreateRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    // the model for this route is a new empty Ember.Object
    return Em.Object.create({});
  },

  renderTemplate: function(){
    this.render('user.create', {
      controller: 'usersCreate'
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transition to a route can be called from ember `routes` by calling `transitionTo("the_route")` and `controllers` by calling `transitionToRoute("the_route")`. If it is required to transition from an ember `view` then call within the view `this.controller.transitionToRoute("users");`.

In the following example some tweaks have been made in `create user` to experiment with the bootstrap modal fade in/out, but generally your code style has been followed to demonstrate what i think you describe.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ASAPASU/1#/users

Comment: thanks for the great jsbin! This works perfectly when I click on cancel, but when I save a new record, the modal closes but the page remains faded out and the url is still at /users/newuserid. Any suggestions?

Comment: @bookthief glad it helped! it seems ok, when i choose `save` two alert dialogs are shown and it transitions to users (tested in chrome 31.x , ff 25.0).

Comment: Hmm I'm making a mistake somewhere as the alert in the View isn't being triggered!